# Why do I get a "local variable defined in enclosing scope" error searching a BST?

Tags: python, oop, binary-tree

I tried answering the following question ([leetcode link](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/)):

> Given the root node of a binary search tree, return the sum of values of all nodes with value between L and R (inclusive).
>   The binary search tree is guaranteed to have unique values.

This is the official solution:

```
class Solution:

    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:

        def dfs(node):

            if node:
                if L <= node.val <= R:
                    self.total += node.val
                if L <= node.val:
                    dfs(node.left)
                if node.val <= R:
                    dfs(node.right)

        self.total = 0
        dfs(root)
        return self.total

solution = Solution()
print(solution.rangeSumBST(root, L, R))
```

It works as expected, for example for the following input: `root = [10,5,15,3,7,null,18], L = 7, R = 15`, the output is `32`. But why is there an error if I write it as a plain function without the class statement?

```
def rangeSumBST(root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:

    def dfs(node):

        if node:
            if L <= node.val <= R:
                total += node.val
            if L <= node.val:
                dfs(node.left)
            if node.val <= R:
                dfs(node.right)

    total = 0
    dfs(root)
    return total

print(rangeSumBST(root, L, R))
```

This is the error-message: `Local variable 'total' defined in enclosing scope on line 75 referenced before assignment... (pyflakes E)` The second piece of code looks almost identical, but I can't tell why the object-oriented style of the solution works while I get an error writing it as a plain function. Obviously there is something wrong with the 'total' variable, but shouldn't a variable defined outside the scope of a function also be accessible inside the scope of the function?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example reproducing your problem:

```
def enclosing():
    def inner():
        total += 1

    total = 0
    inner()
    return total

enclosing()
```

This raises the error:

```
----> 3         total += 1
      4 
      5     total = 0

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

This is perfectly normal: Python considers that a variable is local if you assign to it anywhere in a function. So, `total` is considered local in `inner`, and you try to increment it though you haven't given it a value, hence the error. The same would happen with a top-level function and a global variable `total`.

You don't have the same problem with the method, as `self` doesn't have anything assigned to it, you just change the value of its `total` attribute.

The solution here would be to tell Python to look up `total` in the enclosing scope, that's what the `nonlocal` keyword was introduced for in Python 3 (see [PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/)):

> The nonlocal statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to
>   previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding
>   globals. This is important because the default behavior for binding is
>   to search the local namespace first. The statement allows encapsulated
>   code to rebind variables outside of the local scope besides the global
>   (module) scope.
>
> Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global
>   statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope
>   (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be
>   determined unambiguously).

```
def enclosing():
    def inner():
        nonlocal total
        total += 1

    total = 0
    inner()
    return total

enclosing()
# 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that the best solution for accessing variables from the enclosing scope in the inner scope is to use either a class or the nonlocal keyword? Or are there solutions that are considered better programming style?

Comment: Both are perfectly OK!

Answer (score 1):

Because a function should only depend on it's arguments, and maybe some global variables but not the local variables in it's context.

`total` is defined in the context of `rangeSumBST` function which *encloses* the context in which you call your `dfs` function. But that is not good.

Because if someone else wants to use your dfs function without reading its definition, they will never know that they should have a variable names `totoal` defined in whatever context that they want to use your function and that will make your function coupled to it's calling context.

Something like this should work:

```
def rangeSumBST(root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:

    def dfs(node, total):
        if node:
            if L <= node.val <= R:
                return total + node.val
            if L <= node.val:
                return dfs(node.left, total)
            if node.val <= R:
                return dfs(node.right, total)

    return dfs(root, 0)
```

Comment: I get that. But would you say then that it should work with 'total' defined not in the enclosing scope but globally? Because in this case I get the same error.

Comment: @MoritzWolff No, that Is also a bad pattern because total is not needed globally. You should figure out a way to pass total to your dfs function as an argument and also return it.